# Reference class in browser friendly and node.js friendly way

Tags: coffeescript

I've got the following code at the top of my CoffeeScript
program to reference a BinaryNode class from a BinaryTree 
class.

Since I want to be able to use the BinaryTree class from 
a node.js program or from the browser I have the following 
if/else statement to reference the BinaryNode.

file: BinaryTree.coffee

```
isNodeJs = exports?
if isNodeJs
    {BinaryNode} = require('./binary_node')
else
    BinaryNode = window.BinaryNode

class BinaryTree
    (code for BinaryTree goes here)
```

Somehow this if/else bugs me specially if I will need to 
add it on a lot of different classes that make up the 
program.

Are there any other better ways to perform this check?

Comment: Well, you can probably shorten it to `{BinaryNode} = require?("/.binary_node") or window` if you want

Comment: Thanks. That's much cleaner. I was starting to look into RequireJS but wanted to avoid an extra library and your idea does the trick!

Comment: Should I add it as a proper answer, or do you just want to close the question?

Comment: Go ahead and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From my comment above)*

The branching can be shortened to:

```
{BinaryNode} = require?("/.binary_node") or window
```

(provided you don't have a global `require` function somewhere in your browser code, of course)